# bring child node close to the parent node in d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am trying to develop a tree graph where there is a center node which will have 4 child node. Those 
child node will have 7 different nodes but those 7 different nodes should be shown just near its parent node like in the attached diagram. If i try to decrease the value to bring them closer, one of the side(either left side or right side) of the tree gets messed up.

here is what I have done

```css
line.link {
  stroke: black;
}

line.hard--link {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <svg className='spider-graph-svg'>
  </svg>
  <script>
    var data = {
      "name": "root@gmail.com",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Person Name 1",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "Person name 2",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "Person Name 3",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "Person Name 4",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }]
    };


    const LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH = 13;
    let flagForChildren = false;
    let groups = [];
    data.children.forEach(d => {
      let a = [];
      if (d.children.length > 0) {
        flagForChildren = true;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < d.children.length; i += 2) {
        let b = d.children.slice(i, i + 2);
        if (b[0] && b[1]) {
          a.push(Object.assign(b[0], {
            children: [b[1]]
          }));
        } else {
          let child = b[0];
          if (i >= 6) {
            child = Object.assign(child, {
              children: [{
                name: "..."
              }]
            });
          }
          a.push(child);
        }
      }
      d.children = a;
      groups.push(d);
    });

    data.children = groups;
    let split_index = Math.round(data.children.length / 2);
    let rectangleHeight = 45;
    let leftData = {
      name: data.name,
      children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(0, split_index)))
    };
    let leftDataArray = [];
    leftDataArray.push(leftData);

    // Right data
    let rightData = {
      name: data.name,
      children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(split_index)))
    };
    // Create d3 hierarchies
    let right = d3.hierarchy(rightData);
    let left = d3.hierarchy(leftData);
    // Render both trees
    drawTree(right, "right");
    drawTree(left, "left");

    // draw single tree
    function drawTree(root, pos) {
      let SWITCH_CONST = 1;
      if (pos === "left") {
        SWITCH_CONST = -1;
      }
      const margin = {
          top: 20,
          right: 120,
          bottom: 20,
          left: 120
        },
        width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      let svg = d3
        .select("svg")
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr('view-box', '0 0 ' + (width + margin.right) + ' ' + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
        .style("margin-top", "20px")
        .style("margin-left", "88px");

      const div = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

      // Shift the entire tree by half it's width
      let g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ",0)");

      let deductWidthValue = flagForChildren ? 0 : width * 0.33;
      // Create new default tree layout
      let tree = d3
        .tree()
        // Set the size
        // Remember the tree is rotated
        // so the height is used as the width
        // and the width as the height
        .size([height - 50, SWITCH_CONST * (width - deductWidthValue) / 2])
        .separation((a, b) => a.parent === b.parent ? 4 : 4.25);

      tree(root);

      let nodes = root.descendants();
      let links = root.links();
      // Set both root nodes to be dead center vertically
      nodes[0].x = height / 2;

      // Create links
      let link = g
        .selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter();

      link
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            return 'link'
          } else {
            return 'hard--link'
          }
        })
        .attr("x1", function(d) {
          if (
            d.target.depth === 3
          ) {
            return 0;
          }
          return d.source.y + 100 / 2; //d.source.y + 100/2
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          if (
            d.target.depth === 3
          ) {
            return 0;
          } else if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            return d.target.y;
          }
          return d.target.y + 100 / 2; //d.target.y + 100/2;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          if (
            d.target.depth === 3
          ) {
            return 0;
          }
          return d.source.x + 50 / 2;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          if (
            d.target.depth === 3
          ) {
            return 0;
          } else if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            return d.target.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH / 2;
          }
          return d.target.x + 50 / 2;
        });

      //Rectangle width

      let node = g
        .selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          const dynamicLength = (d.data.topic_name && d.data.topic_name.length) ||
            (d.data.name && d.data.name.length);
          const rectWidth = dynamicLength <= 3 ? '60px' : `${dynamicLength * 8}px`;
          div.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 1);
          div.html(d.data.topic_name || d.data.name)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("width", rectWidth)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("vertical-align", "baseline")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", d => {
          div.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
        })
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) { // this is the leaf node
            if (d.parent.parent.parent) {
              return (
                "translate(" +
                d.parent.y +
                "," +
                (d.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH + 15) +
                ")"
              );
            }
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
          }
          // Select the node with height 2
          if (d.height === 2) {
            //Lets line this up with its 2nd child (index = 1)
            //If y of this child is <0, it means the parent and the child
            //both are on the left
            //side (with margin of 20 between parent and child)
            if (d.children[1]['y'] < 0) {
              return "translate(" + (d.children[1]['y'] + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH + 20) + "," + d.children[1]['x'] + ")"
              // Else both parent and child are on the right.
              //Now we also need to take into consideration the width
              //of the rectangle (with margin of 20 between parent and child)
            } else {
              return "translate(" + (d.children[1]['y'] - rectangleWidth(d) - 20) + "," + (d['x']) + ")"
            }
          } else {
            //This is the root of the tree.
            //Subtract d.y by half of rectangleWidth because we need it to be in the center
            //Same for d.x
            return "translate(" + (d.y - (rectangleWidth(d) / 2)) + "," + (d.x - (rectangleHeight / 2)) + ")";
          }
        });

      // topic rect
      node
        .append("rect")
        .attr("height", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 15 : rectangleHeight)
        .attr("width", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 15 : rectangleWidth(d))
        .attr("rx", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5)
        .attr("ry", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5)

      // topic edges
      node.append('line')
        .attr('x1', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            return 10
          }
        })
        .attr('x2', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            return 10
          }
        })
        .attr('y1', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            if (d.children) {
              return 0;
            }
            return 40;
          }
        })
        .attr('y2', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            return 40
          }
        })
        .attr('class', 'hard--link')

      // topic names
      node
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", function(d, i) {
          return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 10 : rectangleHeight / 2;
        })
        .attr("dx", function(d, i) {
          if (!(d.parent && d.parent.parent)) {
            return 12;
          } else {
            return 20;
          }
        })
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
          return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? "Black" : "White";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          let name = d.data.topic_name || d.data.name;
          return name.length > 12 ? `${name.substring(0, 12)}...` : name;
        })
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) {
            return pos === "left" && "end"
          }
        })
        .style("font-size", "12")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) {
            return pos === "left" ? "translate(-30,0)" : "translate(5,0)"
          }
        })
    }

    function rectangleWidth(d) {
      const MIN_WIDTH = 50;
      const MAX_WIDTH = 100;
      let dynamicLength = 6;
      if (d.data.topic_name) {
        dynamicLength = d.data.topic_name.length;
      } else if (d.data.name) {
        dynamicLength = d.data.name.length;
      }
      dynamicLength = dynamicLength < 3 ? MIN_WIDTH : MAX_WIDTH;
      return dynamicLength;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

the expected design

**expected design of the last nodes**

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should use a force diagram.

Comment: i have a different kind of design. I have a doubt if its possible from it or not.

Answer (score 2):

The `x` and `y` for the nodes is being calculated by `d3` but the placement doesn't look right maybe because the `height` and the `width` of the `rects` weren't taken into account.

So I made a few changes to the code in the section where you are translating the `rects` based on d3's calculated `x` and `y` like so:

```
.attr("transform", function (d) {
    if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) { // this is the leaf node
        if (d.parent.parent.parent) {
            return (
                "translate(" +
                d.parent.y +
                "," +
                (d.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH + 15) +
                ")"
            );
        }
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    }
        // Select the node with height 2
    if (d.height == 2) {
            //Lets line this up with its 2nd child (index = 1)
            //If y of this child is <0, it means the parent and the child 
            //both are on the left 
            //side (with margin of 20 between parent and child)
        if (d.children[1]['y'] < 0) {
            return "translate(" + (d.children[1]['y'] + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH + 20) + "," + d.children[1]['x'] + ")"
            // Else both parent and child are on the right. 
            //Now we also need to take into consideration the width 
            //of the rectangle (with margin of 20 between parent and child)
        } else {
            return "translate(" + (d.children[1]['y'] - rectangleWidth(d) - 20) + "," + (d['x']) + ")"
        }
    } else {
            //This is the root of the tree.
            //Subtract d.y by half of rectangleWidth because we need it to be in the center
            //Same for d.x
        return "translate(" + (d.y - (rectangleWidth(d) / 2)) + "," + (d.x - (rectangleHeight / 2)) + ")";
    }
});
```

Here's the fiddle with these changes.

```css
body {
  background: black
}

rect {
  fill: darkgreen
}

line {
  stroke: lightgreen;
  stroke-width: 1
}

text {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
}

.tooltip {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <svg className='spider-graph-svg'>
  </svg>
  <script>
    var data = {
      "name": "root@gmail.com",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Person Name 1",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "Person name 2",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "Person Name 3",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "Person Name 4",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }]
    };


    const LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH = 13;
    let flagForChildren = false;
    let groups = [];
    data.children.forEach(d => {
      let a = [];
      if (d.children.length > 0) {
        flagForChildren = true;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < d.children.length; i += 2) {
        let b = d.children.slice(i, i + 2);
        if (b[0] && b[1]) {
          a.push(Object.assign(b[0], {
            children: [b[1]]
          }));
        } else {
          let child = b[0];
          if (i >= 6) {
            child = Object.assign(child, {
              children: [{
                name: "..."
              }]
            });
          }
          a.push(child);
        }
      }
      d.children = a;
      groups.push(d);
    });

    data.children = groups;
    let split_index = Math.round(data.children.length / 2);
    let rectangleHeight = 45;
    let leftData = {
      name: data.name,
      children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(0, split_index)))
    };
    let leftDataArray = [];
    leftDataArray.push(leftData);

    // Right data
    let rightData = {
      name: data.name,
      children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(split_index)))
    };
    // Create d3 hierarchies
    let right = d3.hierarchy(rightData);
    let left = d3.hierarchy(leftData);
    console.log(right.descendants())
    // Render both trees
    drawTree(right, "right");
    drawTree(left, "left");

    // draw single tree
    function drawTree(root, pos) {
      let SWITCH_CONST = 1;
      if (pos === "left") {
        SWITCH_CONST = -1;
      }
      const margin = {
          top: 10,
          right: 10,
          bottom: 10,
          left: 10
        },
        width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      let svg = d3
        .select("svg")
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr('view-box', '0 0 ' + (width + margin.right) + ' ' + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
      /* .style("margin-top", "20px")
      .style("margin-left", "88px"); */

      const div = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

      // Shift the entire tree by half it's width
      let g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ",0)");

      let deductWidthValue = flagForChildren ? 0 : width * 0.33;
      // Create new default tree layout
      let tree = d3
        .tree()
        // Set the size
        // Remember the tree is rotated
        // so the height is used as the width
        // and the width as the height
        .size([height - 50, SWITCH_CONST * (width - deductWidthValue) / 2])
        .separation((a, b) => a.parent === b.parent ? 4 : 4.25);

      tree(root);

      let nodes = root.descendants();
      let links = root.links();
      // Set both root nodes to be dead center vertically
      nodes[0].x = height / 2;

      // Create links
      let link = g
        .selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter();

      link
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            return 'link'
          } else {
            return 'hard--link'
          }
        })
        .attr("x1", function(d) {
          if (d.target.depth === 3) {
            return 0;
          } else if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            if (d.source.y < 0) {
              return (d.source.y + 100 / 2) - 100;
            } else {
              return (d.source.y + 100 / 2)
            }
          }
          return 0; //d.source.y + 100/2
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          if (d.target.depth === 3) {
            return 0;
          } else if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            return d.target.y + 10;
          } else if (d.target.depth === 1) {
            if (d.target.y < 0) {
              return d.target.y - 100 / 2
            } else {
              return d.target.y + 100 / 2;
            }
          }
          return d.target.y + 100 / 2; //d.target.y + 100/2;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          if (d.target.depth === 3) {
            return 0;
          } else if (d.target.depth === 1) {
            return (d.source.x + 50 / 2) - 20;
          } else {
            return d.source.x + 50 / 2;
          }
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          if (d.target.depth === 3) {
            return 0;
          } else if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            return d.target.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH / 2;
          }
          return d.target.x + 50 / 2;
        });

      //Rectangle width

      let node = g
        .selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          const dynamicLength = (d.data.topic_name && d.data.topic_name.length) ||
            (d.data.name && d.data.name.length);
          const rectWidth = dynamicLength <= 3 ? '60px' : `${dynamicLength * 8}px`;
          div.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 1);
          div.html(d.data.topic_name || d.data.name)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("width", rectWidth)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("vertical-align", "baseline")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", d => {
          div.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
        })
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) { // this is the leaf node
            if (d.parent.parent.parent) {
              return (
                "translate(" +
                d.parent.y +
                "," +
                (d.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH + 15) +
                ")"
              );
            }
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
          }
          // Select the node with height 2
          if (d.height == 2) {
            //Lets line this up with its 2nd child (index = 1)
            //If y of this child is <0, it means the parent and the child 
            //both are on the left 
            //side (with margin of 20 between parent and child)
            if (d.children[1]['y'] < 0) {
              return "translate(" + (d.children[1]['y'] + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH + 20) + "," + d.children[1]['x'] + ")"
              // Else both parent and child are on the right. 
              //Now we also need to take into consideration the width 
              //of the rectangle (with margin of 20 between parent and child)
            } else {
              return "translate(" + (d.children[1]['y'] - rectangleWidth(d) - 20) + "," + (d['x']) + ")"
            }
          } else {
            //This is the root of the tree.
            //Subtract d.y by half of rectangleWidth because we need it to be in the center
            //Same for d.x
            return "translate(" + (d.y - (rectangleWidth(d) / 2)) + "," + (d.x - (rectangleHeight / 2)) + ")";
          }
        })
        .on('click', function(d) {
          console.log(d)
        });

      // topic rect
      node
        .append("rect")
        .attr("height", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 15 : rectangleHeight)
        .attr("width", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 15 : rectangleWidth(d))
        .attr("rx", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5)
        .attr("ry", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5)

      // topic edges
      node.append('line')
        .attr('x1', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            return 10
          }
        })
        .attr('x2', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            return 10
          }
        })
        .attr('y1', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            if (d.children) {
              return 0;
            }
            return 40;
          }
        })
        .attr('y2', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            return 40
          }
        })
        .attr('class', 'hard--link')

      // topic names
      node
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", function(d, i) {
          return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 10 : rectangleHeight / 2;
        })
        .attr("dx", function(d, i) {
          if (!(d.parent && d.parent.parent)) {
            return 12;
          } else {
            return 20;
          }
        })
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
          return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? "White" : "White";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          let name = d.data.topic_name || d.data.name;
          return name.length > 12 ? `${name.substring(0, 12)}...` : name;
        })
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) {
            return pos === "left" && "end"
          }
        })
        .style("font-size", "12")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) {
            return pos === "left" ? "translate(-30,0)" : "translate(5,0)"
          }
        })
    }

    function rectangleWidth(d) {
      const MIN_WIDTH = 50;
      const MAX_WIDTH = 100;
      let dynamicLength = 6;
      if (d.data.topic_name) {
        dynamicLength = d.data.topic_name.length;
      } else if (d.data.name) {
        dynamicLength = d.data.name.length;
      }
      dynamicLength = dynamicLength < 3 ? MIN_WIDTH : MAX_WIDTH;
      return dynamicLength;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Massive thanks for the solution. I was striving for this since a week. The leaf nodes are closer to its parent now but if you use the edges to show the link, it looks messy. Can you give me idea on that, please?

Comment: for other four nodes, i think i have to do the same like you have done to bring them a bit closer like in the diagram to the root node(center node)

Comment: @justforpbasnet also what are the other 4 nodes?

Comment: person name (I mean level 2 nodes).Level 1 is root@gmail.com and level2 are the Person Name and level 3 branch 4.2.

Comment: @justforpbasnet I was able to incorporate the changes successfully. Please check the updated fiddle.

Comment: why it is shown like this in mine on that snippet https://i.imgur.com/Jpm91k5.png

Comment: @justforpbasnet Will your tree graph have a fixed width? Looks like my code will work fine for smaller widths. I tried to fix it to work with any size, but alas, it didn't work. If your graph will have a fixed width, try playing around with code. You should be able to do it.

Comment: it will have a fixed width. Sure I will try this.

Comment: @justforpbasnet Great! Please mark as accepted and close the question if that solved your problem. Thanks.