# show checkbox inside node while hovering on that node

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I wanted to show the checkbox when hovering on the node so that when the checkbox is clicked the name of that node should be shown at the top of the spider graph and if unticked then that name should disappear.

I used the mouseover event to show the checkbox but is not working

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style('cursor', 'pointer')
            .html('<input type="checkbox" name="name" class="checkbox" />')
        })
```

Here is the full code with demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <svg className='spider-graph-svg'>
  </svg>
  <script>
    var data = {
      "name": "root@gmail.com",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Person Name 1",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "Person name 2",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "Person Name 3",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "Person Name 4",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }]
    };


    const LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH = 13;
    let flagForChildren = false;
    let groups = [];
    data.children.forEach(d => {
      let a = [];
      if (d.children.length > 0) {
        flagForChildren = true;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < d.children.length; i += 2) {
        let b = d.children.slice(i, i + 2);
        if (b[0] && b[1]) {
          a.push(Object.assign(b[0], {
            children: [b[1]]
          }));
        } else {
          let child = b[0];
          if (i >= 6) {
            child = Object.assign(child, {
              children: [{
                name: "..."
              }]
            });
          }
          a.push(child);
        }
      }
      d.children = a;
      groups.push(d);
    });

    data.children = groups;
    let split_index = Math.round(data.children.length / 2);
    let rectangleHeight = 45;
    let leftData = {
      name: data.name,
      children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(0, split_index)))
    };
    let leftDataArray = [];
    leftDataArray.push(leftData);

    // Right data
    let rightData = {
      name: data.name,
      children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(split_index)))
    };
    // Create d3 hierarchies
    let right = d3.hierarchy(rightData);
    let left = d3.hierarchy(leftData);
    // Render both trees
    drawTree(right, "right");
    drawTree(left, "left");

    // draw single tree
    function drawTree(root, pos) {
      let SWITCH_CONST = 1;
      if (pos === "left") {
        SWITCH_CONST = -1;
      }
      const margin = {
          top: 20,
          right: 120,
          bottom: 20,
          left: 120
        },
        width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      let svg = d3
        .select("svg")
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr('view-box', '0 0 ' + (width + margin.right) + ' ' + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
        .style("margin-top", "20px")
        .style("margin-left", "88px");

      const myTool = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "mytooltip")
        .style("opacity", "0")
        .style("display", "none");;


      // Shift the entire tree by half it's width
      let g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ",0)");

      let deductWidthValue = flagForChildren ? 0 : width * 0.33;
      // Create new default tree layout
      let tree = d3
        .tree()
        // Set the size
        // Remember the tree is rotated
        // so the height is used as the width
        // and the width as the height
        .size([height - 50, SWITCH_CONST * (width - deductWidthValue) / 2])
        .separation((a, b) => a.parent === b.parent ? 4 : 4.25);

      tree(root);

      let nodes = root.descendants();
      let links = root.links();
      // Set both root nodes to be dead center vertically
      nodes[0].x = height / 2;

      // Create links
      let link = g
        .selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter();

      link
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            return 'link'
          } else {
            return 'hard--link'
          }
        })
        .attr("x1", function(d) {
          if (
            d.target.depth === 3
          ) {
            return 0;
          }
          return d.source.y + 100 / 2; //d.source.y + 100/2
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          if (
            d.target.depth === 3
          ) {
            return 0;
          } else if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            return d.target.y;
          }
          return d.target.y + 100 / 2; //d.target.y + 100/2;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          if (
            d.target.depth === 3
          ) {
            return 0;
          }
          return d.source.x + 50 / 2;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          if (
            d.target.depth === 3
          ) {
            return 0;
          } else if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            return d.target.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH / 2;
          }
          return d.target.x + 50 / 2;
        });

      //Rectangle width

      let node = g
        .selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style('cursor', 'pointer')
            .html('<input type="checkbox" name="name" class="checkbox" />')
        })
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) { // this is the leaf node
            if (d.parent.parent.parent) {
              return (
                "translate(" +
                d.parent.y +
                "," +
                (d.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH + 15) +
                ")"
              );
            }
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
          }
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });

      // topic rect
      node
        .append("rect")
        .attr("height", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 15 : rectangleHeight)
        .attr("width", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 15 : rectangleWidth(d))
        .attr("rx", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5)
        .attr("ry", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5)

      // topic edges
      node.append('line')
        .attr('x1', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            return 10
          }
        })
        .attr('x2', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            return 10
          }
        })
        .attr('y1', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            if (d.children) {
              return 0;
            }
            return 40;
          }
        })
        .attr('y2', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            return 40
          }
        })
        .attr('class', 'hard--link')

      // topic names
      node
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", function(d, i) {
          return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 10 : rectangleHeight / 2;
        })
        .attr("dx", function(d, i) {
          if (!(d.parent && d.parent.parent)) {
            return 12;
          } else {
            return 20;
          }
        })
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
          return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? "Black" : "White";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          let name = d.data.topic_name || d.data.name;
          return name.length > 12 ? `${name.substring(0, 12)}...` : name;
        })
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) {
            return pos === "left" && "end"
          }
        })
        .style("font-size", "12")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) {
            return pos === "left" ? "translate(-30,0)" : "translate(5,0)"
          }
        })
    }

    function rectangleWidth(d) {
      const MIN_WIDTH = 50;
      const MAX_WIDTH = 100;
      let dynamicLength = 6;
      if (d.data.topic_name) {
        dynamicLength = d.data.topic_name.length;
      } else if (d.data.name) {
        dynamicLength = d.data.name.length;
      }
      dynamicLength = dynamicLength < 3 ? MIN_WIDTH : MAX_WIDTH;
      return dynamicLength;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `input` element is not an `svg` element, you cannot simply insert a checkbox like and make it work like an html element. We would have to make use of `foreignObject` and append the `input` inside it.

Once you create those small `rects`, we need to append a `foreignObject` containing our checkboxes and hide them initially like so:

```
// topic rect
node
  .append("rect")
  .attr("height", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 15 : rectangleHeight)
  .attr("width", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 15 : rectangleWidth(d))
  .attr("rx", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5)
  .attr("ry", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5)

node.append('foreignObject').attr('width', '40')
    .attr('height', '40').append('xhtml:input')
    .attr('type', 'checkbox').style('display', 'none')
    // An on click function for the checkboxes
    .on("click",function(d){
        console.log(d)
    });
```

When the user hovers over the `rects` we can then simply unhide the checkboxes, and hide them again if they are not checked (else keep showing until user unchecks) :

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  d3.select(this).select('input').style('display', '');
})
.on('mouseout', function(d) {
  if (!d3.select(this).select('input').property('checked')) {
    d3.select(this).select('input').style('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

Here is the full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <svg className='spider-graph-svg'>
  </svg>
  <script>
    var prevElem;
    var data = {
      "name": "root@gmail.com",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Person Name 1",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "Person name 2",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "Person Name 3",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "Person Name 4",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Branch 4.1"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }, {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "Branch 4.2"
          }
        ]
      }]
    };


    const LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH = 13;
    let flagForChildren = false;
    let groups = [];
    data.children.forEach(d => {
      let a = [];
      if (d.children.length > 0) {
        flagForChildren = true;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < d.children.length; i += 2) {
        let b = d.children.slice(i, i + 2);
        if (b[0] && b[1]) {
          a.push(Object.assign(b[0], {
            children: [b[1]]
          }));
        } else {
          let child = b[0];
          if (i >= 6) {
            child = Object.assign(child, {
              children: [{
                name: "..."
              }]
            });
          }
          a.push(child);
        }
      }
      d.children = a;
      groups.push(d);
    });

    data.children = groups;
    let split_index = Math.round(data.children.length / 2);
    let rectangleHeight = 45;
    let leftData = {
      name: data.name,
      children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(0, split_index)))
    };
    let leftDataArray = [];
    leftDataArray.push(leftData);

    // Right data
    let rightData = {
      name: data.name,
      children: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(split_index)))
    };
    // Create d3 hierarchies
    let right = d3.hierarchy(rightData);
    let left = d3.hierarchy(leftData);
    // Render both trees
    drawTree(right, "right");
    drawTree(left, "left");

    // draw single tree
    function drawTree(root, pos) {
      let SWITCH_CONST = 1;
      if (pos === "left") {
        SWITCH_CONST = -1;
      }
      const margin = {
          top: 20,
          right: 120,
          bottom: 20,
          left: 120
        },
        width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      let svg = d3
        .select("svg")
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr('view-box', '0 0 ' + (width + margin.right) + ' ' + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
        .style("margin-top", "20px")
        .style("margin-left", "88px");

      const myTool = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "mytooltip")
        .style("opacity", "0")
        .style("display", "none");;


      // Shift the entire tree by half it's width
      let g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ",0)");

      let deductWidthValue = flagForChildren ? 0 : width * 0.33;
      // Create new default tree layout
      let tree = d3
        .tree()
        // Set the size
        // Remember the tree is rotated
        // so the height is used as the width
        // and the width as the height
        .size([height - 50, SWITCH_CONST * (width - deductWidthValue) / 2])
        .separation((a, b) => a.parent === b.parent ? 4 : 4.25);

      tree(root);

      let nodes = root.descendants();
      let links = root.links();
      // Set both root nodes to be dead center vertically
      nodes[0].x = height / 2;

      // Create links
      let link = g
        .selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter();

      link
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            return 'link'
          } else {
            return 'hard--link'
          }
        })
        .attr("x1", function(d) {
          if (
            d.target.depth === 3
          ) {
            return 0;
          }
          return d.source.y + 100 / 2; //d.source.y + 100/2
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          if (
            d.target.depth === 3
          ) {
            return 0;
          } else if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            return d.target.y;
          }
          return d.target.y + 100 / 2; //d.target.y + 100/2;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          if (
            d.target.depth === 3
          ) {
            return 0;
          }
          return d.source.x + 50 / 2;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          if (
            d.target.depth === 3
          ) {
            return 0;
          } else if (d.target.depth === 2) {
            return d.target.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH / 2;
          }
          return d.target.x + 50 / 2;
        });

      //Rectangle width
      let node = g
        .selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).select('input').style('display', '')
        })

        .on('mouseout', function(d) {
          if (!d3.select(this).select('input').property('checked')) {
            d3.select(this).select('input').style('display', 'none')
          }
        })
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) { // this is the leaf node
            if (d.parent.parent.parent) {
              return (
                "translate(" +
                d.parent.y +
                "," +
                (d.x + LAST_CHILDREN_WIDTH + 15) +
                ")"
              );
            }
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
          }
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });

      // topic rect
      node
        .append("rect")
        .attr("height", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 15 : rectangleHeight)
        .attr("width", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 15 : rectangleWidth(d))
        .attr("rx", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5)
        .attr("ry", (d, i) => d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 5 : 5)


      // Create foreign object checkboxes and keep them hidden
      node.append('foreignObject').attr('width', '40').attr('height', '40').append('xhtml:input').attr('type', 'checkbox').style('display', 'none')

      // topic edges
      node.append('line')
        .attr('x1', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            return 10
          }
        })
        .attr('x2', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            return 10
          }
        })
        .attr('y1', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            if (d.children) {
              return 0;
            }
            return 40;
          }
        })
        .attr('y2', d => {
          if (d.depth === 2) {
            return 40
          }
        })
        .attr('class', 'hard--link')

      // topic names
      node
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", function(d, i) {
          return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? 10 : rectangleHeight / 2;
        })
        .attr("dx", function(d, i) {
          if (!(d.parent && d.parent.parent)) {
            return 12;
          } else {
            return 20;
          }
        })
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
          return d.parent && d.parent.parent ? "Black" : "White";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          let name = d.data.topic_name || d.data.name;
          return name.length > 12 ? `${name.substring(0, 12)}...` : name;
        })
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) {
            return pos === "left" && "end"
          }
        })
        .style("font-size", "12")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          if (d.parent && d.parent.parent) {
            return pos === "left" ? "translate(-30,0)" : "translate(5,0)"
          }
        })
    }

    function rectangleWidth(d) {
      const MIN_WIDTH = 50;
      const MAX_WIDTH = 100;
      let dynamicLength = 6;
      if (d.data.topic_name) {
        dynamicLength = d.data.topic_name.length;
      } else if (d.data.name) {
        dynamicLength = d.data.name.length;
      }
      dynamicLength = dynamicLength < 3 ? MIN_WIDTH : MAX_WIDTH;
      return dynamicLength;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm sure you can do the rest from here.

Comment: so if i want the event handler in the input field i have to use .on('click', function(d){ and this d will have the object }) right?

Comment: @justforpbasnet Right after you create the foreignObject and append the input, add an on click function. Check the updated code block above (Not in the fiddle)

Comment: Huge Thanks for helping on this. Can you help me at this, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206983/bring-child-node-close-to-the-parent-node-in-d3 . I could not get help from the d3 slack channel either. I am struggling to achieve that since a week

Comment: @justforpbasnet Sure.. I'll try my best. Glad I could help.

Comment: That would be awesome help ever to me. Warm thanks again.